# Lisf of avaliable servers on ssh login

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh

I'm having some problems with switching between servers using ssh, on my universitys Linux servers.

The servers I'm using are set up such that I am sent to an initial login server once I run ssh ...@login.... from my terminal. As the login-server is not meant for heavy computations I usually switch to another server after login, by simply writing that server's name. However, this server is full at times (since a lot of different people are using it), and I'd like to switch to another server at the same network. The problem is that I don't know any of the other servers' names, so I'm looking for a command to list all available servers from the login-server.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with NMAP, I am not an NMAP expert but hopefully you can take a look and get it working for you.

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6853/get-a-list-of-ssh-servers-on-the-local-subnet

The bottom option:

```
nmap -p 22 --open -sV XX.XX.XX.XX/XX
```

will scan for port 22 being open displaying the Version number across the IP subnet range...I would recommend better understanding nmap.  Hope it at least gets you started!  You could always ask your universities IT dept for a list of server names as a shortcut...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I eventually got a hold of a network administrator, and turns out they had written a script for listing all available server areas, so I just needed the correct script name.